# Watin : Validate link of child browser and closing it

Tags: c#, watin

I'm trying to find a way to close a child browser, the idea is when the browser pops up(currently using IE & tab for mozilla)it will load and then closes.

The only thing i can think of is inserting this after the browser opened

```
 IE newIE = new IE();
 newIE.Close();
```

Sadly it doesn't worked.I know watin can open two or three browsers but can it open and shift to another browser and then go back to the main browser

Main browser => child browser(close this) => Main browser

What am i missing here?

I tried something like this but it doesn't work

```
IE ie = IE.AttachToIE(Find.ByUrl("google.com"));
ie.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar in some of my tests and I was having some problems too. You may find that adding a thread sleep will help. This is what I had:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
IE popUpWindow = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl(s =>s.StartsWith("http://www.google.com")));
Assert.IsTrue(popUpWindow.Title.Contains("google - Google Search"));
popUpWindow.Close();
```